# How can I treat variables symmetrically or jointly in a random forest model in R?

Tags: r, random-forest

I am trying to model correlations of stock returns.

The correlations are assumed to be functions of firm variables.

p = f(w,[(X1,X2),(Y1,Y2)])$

where w are parameters and X and Y are firm characteristics. The subscripts 1 and 2 are arbitrary. You could reverse them.

For a gam I could use (for instance):

```
corr.gam <- gam(corr ~ s(X1,X2,df=1)+s(Y1,Y2,df=1), data=df)
```

Which captures that it's the relationship between X1 and X2 that are predicted to have a relationship with correlation.  For instance, if X is market value of the firm, two big firms might be more correlated than two small firms.

Is there a way to tell R that the trees it builds should be on the relationships between variables?  Or maybe a different way to formulate the problem entirely?

Comment: This kind of defeats the point of using a non-parametric model that models high dimensional interactions. Your correlations assume a linear relationship whereas random forests is fitting a set of nonlinear functions. But, no you cannot inform random forests in a way that builds the ensemble following a correlation structure in x. This would horribly bias the model. The RF model should capture the interaction that you illustrate and can be explored using bivariate partial plots.

Comment: The correlations are of a different variable (z) like stock returns.  So big companies (X) or profitable companies (Y) may be more or less correlated with each other than small or unprofitable companies.  That relationship is allowed to be non-linear.  But I take the point that I can just put everything in and use symmetry as sort of a check on the model.  It does seem inefficient, though.